One flip coin game
Nate has $n \geq 2$ coins $\{C_i\}_{0 \leq i \leq n-1}$ that each turn up heads with probability $\frac{i}{n-1}$ each, but he is not sure which ones are which.
He has \$1 with which to bet with. On each round, he makes a double-or-nothing bet with any amount up to his entire fortune, and including zero, on one of the coins turning up either heads or tails.
Upon betting on each of the coins and the result being shown, it disintegrates into thin air, and Nate can only bet on the remaining coins in subsequent rounds.
Question: How can Nate maximise his expected value from this game after $n$ flips, and what is the maximal expected value?

Should not Nste always bet on the remaining coin which was heads most often so far?

Ah, the coins may only be used once! @FedorPetrov

Nate should only do zero-or-everything bets? Can Nate do better than betting everything on the last coin if he has only seen Tails in the previous rounds? He gets 1+(1/n) from this.

I am sure there is a more sophisticated strategy, but I am not sure what it is :kek: @martincripps

This seems like the secretary problem vaguely…

@user479223 I thought that too but this is tricker. Stochastic dynamic  programming does not seem to work in this case. An old book by Dubbins and Savage "How to gamble if you must" has many gems and there might be some helpful ideas there.

On a side note, I like this way of speaking of oneself in third person,  it reminds Julius Caesar in De bello gallico

@PietroMajer : But maybe it's a different Nate? :-)

@PietroMajer Now Nate is self conscious :P

At every step, it is optimal to bet your entire fortune on either heads or tails. One optimal strategy is thus to alternately guess heads and tails and always bet your entire fortune. The resulting expected value is $2^n$ times the probability that indeed the coins alternate heads and tails. I can not find a formula for the answer, but I calculated the following values with dynamic programming.
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
n&E=&E\approx \\ \hline
2&2&2.00000\ldots \\
3&4/3&1.33333\ldots \\
4&40/27&1.48148\ldots \\
5&13/10&1.30000\ldots \\
6&4304/3125&1.37728\ldots \\
7&3632/2835&1.28112\ldots \\
8&5488768/4117715&1.33296\ldots \\
9&13651/10752&1.26962\ldots \\
10&394291456/301327047&1.30851\ldots \\
100&&1.23219\ldots \\
200&&1.22844\ldots \\
300&&1.22720\ldots \\
400&&1.22658\ldots \\
500&&1.22621\ldots \\
1000&&1.22548\ldots \\
2000&&1.22511\ldots \\
3000&&1.22498\ldots \\
\end{array}
To prove my claim, for $f_1,\ldots,f_k\in\{H,T\}$ let $E(f_1,\ldots,f_k)$ be the maximum possible expected value if the first $k$ coin flips have outcome $f_1,\ldots,f_k$ and we have $1$ dollar at that point. Let $p$ be the probability that, given the first $k$ coin flips are $f_1,\ldots,f_k$, the next coin flip is $H$.
Betting $x$ dollars on $H$ has outcome
\begin{align*}
&p(1+x)E(f_1,\ldots,f_k,H)+(1-p)(1-x)E(f_1,\ldots,f_k,T)
\\&=pE(f_1,\ldots,f_k,H)+(1-p)E(f_1,\ldots,f_k,T)\\&+x[pE(f_1,\ldots,f_k,H)-(1-p)E(f_1,\ldots,f_k,T)],
\end{align*}
while betting $x$ dollars on $T$ has outcome
\begin{align*}
&p(1-x)E(f_1,\ldots,f_k,H)+(1-p)(1+x)E(f_1,\ldots,f_k,T)
\\&=pE(f_1,\ldots,f_k,H)+(1-p)E(f_1,\ldots,f_k,T)\\&-x[pE(f_1,\ldots,f_k,H)-(1-p)E(f_1,\ldots,f_k,T)].
\end{align*}
It is thus optimal to choose $x$ as large as possible, such that you bet your entire fortune, while betting on $H$ if $pE(f_1,\ldots,f_k,H)-(1-p)E(f_1,\ldots,f_k,T)$ is positive and betting on $T$ otherwise.
This strategy has the consequence that your choices do not matter anymore as soon as you made a wrong guess. You thus might as well predetermine the entire sequence of heads and tails that you want to guess. Then you either win $2^n$ if your sequence was correct, or you are left with $0$ otherwise. The expected value is thus $2^n$ times the probability your sequence is correct. We thus want to optimize the probability that your sequence is correct.
I interpret the fact that Nate is not sure which coin is which as the permutation of coins being uniformly random. Then the probability that your sequence is correct is independent of its permutation, so we only need to consider how many heads and tails you guess.
We have the following probability generating function for the number of heads occurrences. $$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{i}{n-1}x+\frac{n-1-i}{n-1}\right)$$ I expanded this product with dynamic programming and took the largest coefficient times $2^n$ to obtain the answers in the table. This largest coefficient was always at the median, meaning $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ and $\lceil n/2\rceil$, though a simple proof that this must always hold currently eludes me. This corresponds to the strategy of alternating heads and tails.
As a final note, I am interested if anyone can determine if the optimal value converges as $n$ tends to infinity. Numerically, it appears the sequence is decreasing for $n$ even and for $n$ odd separately. The difference between $n$ even and $n$ odd seems to converge to $0$. The sequence does not appear to converge to $1$ however. If I had to take a guess I would go with $11/9$, but this is only based on numeric observation.
EDIT The limit is $\sqrt{3/2}=1.22474\ldots$. I give an incomplete argument for $2n$ coins. Then the generating function for number of $H$ minus number of $T$ is $$\prod_{i=0}^{2n-1}\left(\frac{i}{2n-1}x+\left(1-\frac{i}{2n-1}\right)x^{-1}\right)=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{i}{2n-1}x+\left(1-\frac{i}{2n-1}\right)x^{-1}\right)\left(\left(1-\frac{i}{2n-1}\right)x+\frac{i}{2n-1}x^{-1}\right)=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{i}{2n-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{2n-1}\right)(x^2+x^{-2})+1-2\frac{i}{2n-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{2n-1}\right)\right)$$ For $a_i=\frac{i}{2n-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{2n-1}\right)$ we can consider this as a random walk starting in $0$ and for each $i=0,\ldots,n-1$ there is an $a_i$ probability of walking left and an $a_i$ probability of walking right and a $1-2a_i$ probability of staying. Then the expected total number of steps is $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2a_i\sim2n\int_0^1\frac{x}{2}\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)dx=\frac13n.$$ There is a probability of $\frac12$ that the number of steps is even, which is necessary and sufficient for it to be possible to end at $0$. If the number of steps is $2k$ then the probability of ending at $0$ is $$\binom{2k}{k}\left(\frac12\right)^{2k}\sim\frac1{\sqrt{\pi k}}.$$ Assuming the number of steps is sufficiently concentrated, the probability we end at $0$ is thus $$\frac1{2\sqrt{\pi\cdot\frac13n/2}}=\sqrt{\frac3{2\pi n}}.$$ By the generating function, this corresponds to the probability that there are an equal number of heads and tails. The probability that we correctly guess the sequence is thus this divided by $\binom{2n}{n}$, which gives an optimal expected value of $$2^{2n}\cdot\sqrt{\frac3{2\pi n}}\div\binom{2n}{n}\to\sqrt{3/2}.$$ Formalizing this proof requires more careful concentration and parity analysis of the random walk. But together with numerical evidence, I feel like it is safe to say this limit is correct.

Wow, thanks for the really thorough answer! I agree with your proof of the claim that you should always bet your entire fortune to maximise the expected value. It is interesting that the optimal value changes between $n$ odd and even instead of being strictly monotone. The computation of the expected value, even knowing the optimal strategy seems really tough.

@NateRiver It should be obvious why. When $n$ is odd, you get 1 coin which is indifferent to choosing between heads and tails $(p=0.5)$. But when $n$ is even, every coin prefers exactly one of heads and tails $(p \neq 0.5)$.

Well yes, but it is still unclear why betting your entire fortune is always optimal. Of course the computations say so! @Snared

@NateRiver The reason why that should be obvious as well. It is optimal in regards to maximizing your expectation, not maximizing your utility. The utility often involves something like the expectation minus a constant times the standard deviation of your strategy. Setting that constant to zero gives your question, but if this game were about real money that is meaningful to someone, then simply maximizing the expectation would be a losing strategy with respect to maximizing their utility from the game. But the constant chosen for risk is a personal choice, though $0$ is never the best.

It's akin to saying that if I give you a $(1/2+\epsilon)$ coin-flip opportunity to double-or-nothing any amount of money, obviously the best expected value from that would be to flip as much money as you can. But you wouldn't flip your entire net worth because your expected utility falls off a cliff - you "die" $1/2-\epsilon$ amount of the time and are "twice as wealthy" $1/2+\epsilon$ of the time, but it would have been better to just bet say 5% of your net worth so you could still be in the same general band of wealth even if you lose.

Yes, the framework of maximising simple expectation is appropriate when the amount that you get is small enough i suppose. @Snared

The maximal coefficient is at $n/2$ because the sequence of the coefficients of this polynomial is symmetric (obviously) and log-concave by https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_inequalities
